# How to avoid using the To Workspace block

Tags: matlab, io, simulink

I ran the profiler on my Simulink model and realized that the "To Workspace" block is using 20% of the total simulation time. Because this model is ran more than one time, I'm looking for a way to increase its performance.

Hence, is there an alternate solution to using the "To Workspace" block that would increase my model global performance?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [Signal Logging](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/signal-logging.html). The various approaches to logging simulation results are discussed in the documentation under [Export Simulation Data](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/exporting-simulation-data.html). Finally, see also [View Simulation Results](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/about-scope-blocks-signal-viewers-signal-logging-and-test-points.html) for alternative approaches. My personal recommendation would be signal logging or a To File block.

Comment: You can also log at a larger sample rate (if that's acceptable) to avoid using too much memory, of course.

Comment: I need to log the data at each time step.

Comment: I tested Signal logging and it's slower(~15%) than the `To Workspace` block in my model.

Comment: Have you tried logging to a File Block? Other than that, I am not sure what else to suggest (maybe a data store?).

Comment: I would like to avoid using a `To File` block, as it would require loading the generated file multiple times afterward. At each simulation, I'm using the generated data to calculate various parameters. Hence, it's easier if they are in the `baseworkspace` already.

Comment: I tested the `To File` block, and it's ~12% slower.

Comment: I am not sure what else to suggest, other than maybe a data store. Have you tried running your model in accelerator or rapid accelerator mode? You incur a penalty for generating the code in the first place, but the execution should be much faster. Writing data to memory/file is always going to take some time I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

According to my general understanding of memory management, reserving a fixed memory block takes less time than expanding it in each timestep. So, it might be useful to limit the number of data points to be logged, that the memory space reserved for your data set will not be dynamically increased at every timestep. Of course this would be only valid if you would know the number of data points and therefore number of steps in simulation prior to start of the simulation, which can be achieved by a fixed step size solver (if applicable by your simulation system setuo). Thus pre-allocation of the workspace array might save you some time in terms of not reaching the memory management system at each timestep.